# Flutter Using async await requires hotreload but using .then doesn't

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, future, hot-reload

Can anyone help me understand this piece of code:

```
 String? userName = "";   
 String? userEmail = ""; 
 AuthService authService = AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    gettingUserData();
  }
```

while defining gettingUserData(), using async, await needs hotreload to show the email

```
gettingUserData() async {     
setState(() async {       
userName = await HelperFunction.getUsername();       
userEmail = await HelperFunction.getUseremail();     
});   
}
```

But defining it using .then doesn't need hot relaod

```
gettingUserData() {
    HelperFunction.getUseremail().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userEmail = value;
      });
    });

    HelperFunction.getUsername().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        userName = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two versions are not equivalent.  The `Future.then` version calls `setState` *after* each `Future` completes.

The `await` version calls `setState` with an asynchronous callback, which `setState` does not expect.  Since [`setState` expects a `VoidCallback` argument](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html), it expects its callback to complete synchronously, and it will not be `await`ed. `setState` therefore executes and returns *immediately* before waiting for either of the `Future`s complete.

One way to correct your `await` version is to `await` the `Future`s *first* and to then call `setState`:

```dart
Future<void> gettingUserData() async {     
  var userName = await HelperFunction.getUsername();
  var userEmail = await HelperFunction.getUseremail();
  setState(() {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
  });
}
```